# Mute specific program

Tags: macos, audio, firefox

Is there any way to mute a specific program? I want to be able to mute Firefox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/51485/muting-an-application-on-a-mac) an answer from our friends over at SuperUser.

TL;DR: You can, but only with some extra software. They suggest [AudioHijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/)

Comment: What does "TL;DR"  ?

Comment: too long, didn't read.

Comment: @jmlumpkin Really man? His comment wasn't that long, why don't you just tell him what it means? Now I'm curious as well...

Comment: @JShoe I am confused. What's the 'really man' for? TL;DR literally is short for 'too long, didn't read'. In this case, the user answering was stating that 'instead of reading through the answers, the basic gist is to use AudioHijack Pro to mute a specific program'. This is a pretty common thing online to summarize.

Comment: So, my comment was in response to @Rabskatran , with the understanding that his comment was asking 'what does TLDR mean'? (mean is missing in his comment).

Comment: @jmlumpkin It was a joke. Like "Who's on first," I misinterpreted your response to mean that his question was "too long" and that, because of that, you "didn't read."

Answer (score 2):

AudioHijack is the only software I've found that can route application sound. If you are looking to capture/block sound from Chrome/Chromium you are out of luck though. AHP cannot handle that software yet due to the way Chrome's processes are spawned on the fly.